# How to store user string input in array, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, input, store

I am building a choose your own adventure.

So basically, after the user inputs their name I would like the playerList   switch statement to store whatever is entered into basePlayer[].

Also if you are going to run this, you will have to click the down arrow after you enter your name to get to the playerList menu, because its kind of buggy.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mike

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);

string playerList[6] = {"Abbot", "Sear", "Hellion", "Vagabond", "Knave","##QUIT##"};
string cityList[4] = {"city1","city2","city3","city4"};
string spiritList[4] = {"spirit1","spirit2","spirit3","spirit4",};
string yesNo[2] = {"yes","no"};
string name;
string player;
string city;
string spirit;
string basePlayer[4];
    basePlayer[0] = name;
    basePlayer[1] = player;
    basePlayer[2] = city;
    basePlayer[3] = spirit;


int pointer = 0;

while(true){

cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "your name is " << name << "?" << endl;
basePlayer[0] = name;
cout << basePlayer[0];


int pointer = 0;

while(true){
    system("cls");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
    cout << basePlayer[0]<<" please choose your Adventurer:\n*tab* for  description\n\n";

    for (int row = 0; row < 6; ++row){
        if(row == pointer){
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << playerList[row] << endl;}

        else{
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
            cout << playerList[row] << endl;}}

 while(true){

  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
        Beep(800,50);
    pointer -= 1;
    if (pointer == -1){
        pointer = 0;}
            break;}

 else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0){
        Beep(800,50);
    pointer += 1;
    if (pointer == 6){
        pointer = 0;}
            break;}

 else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB) != 0){
        Beep(1200,50);
        Beep(1000,50);

    switch(pointer){
    case 0:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "AbbotFacts.\n\n*Enter* to become the Abbot\n*ArrowDown* to      return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 1:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "SearFacts.\n\n*Enter* to become the Sear\n*ArrowDown* to  return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "HellionFacts.\n\n*Enter* to become the Hellion\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 3:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "VagabondFacts.\n\n*Enter* to become the Vagabond\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 4:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "KnaveFacts.\n\n*Enter* to become the Knave\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 5:{return 0;}
        break;
        break;}}

else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0){
        Beep(1000,50);
        Beep(1200,50);


    switch(pointer){
    case 0:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Abbot"<< endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

        break;
    case 1:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Sear"<< endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Hellion"<< endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 3:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Vagabond" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 4:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the knave"<< endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 5:{return 0;
    break;}
    break;}}
 }
  Sleep(150);
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: It worked? Okay, I'll add that as an answer. Accept it, please. :)

Comment: Alright, all edited.

Comment: ^^ This will run by the way, might make it easier to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: It would be appreciable if you reduce the size of your code to highlight the parts of code in which you are having trouble.

Comment: Sorry, the switch statement that am talking about is on line 120

Comment: I suggest you begin to work out through that code with a debugger first, and if there is a *concrete error*, modify the question.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help shauryachats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the statement `cin.get()` from your program because `cin >> name` inputs the `name`, hence no use for a `cin.get()`.

Comment: Can i still ask you one more question after i make it answered?

Comment: Sure. What do you want to ask?

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Also what do I post in "Your Answer?" Do I just copy past your post?

Comment: You need not post *your answer* as you have got the answer from this post, I guess. You just need to click the tick mark below the upvote-downvote counter in my answer.

Comment: So i have a switch statement:                                                                                                          switch(pointer){
        case 0:{
            system("cls");
            cout << "You have chosen the Abbot"<< endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }

            break;
        case 1:{

        }
            break;
        case 2:{

        }
            break;
        case 3:{

        }
            break;
        case 4:{

        }
            break;
        case 5:{return 0;
        break;}
        break;}}

Comment: Crud, I don't think I can really ask this question in the comments. Im probably going to have to wait 90 to post again :/

Comment: You can edit your question with the code you have added here.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to send you the complete game script.